Manim Latex error converting to dvi
I'm not able to use Latex on Manim due to an error converting dvi. I saw other post about this and I change my code but it still does not work. Here is my code :
from manim import *
class dvi_error(Scene):
def construct(self):
t = MathTex(r"$y = x^2$")
t.scale(2)
self.add(t)
self.wait()
It have this error message :
INFO     Writing $y = x^2$ to media\Tex\88663fadf5843031.tex                                     tex_file_writing.py:107                    ERROR    LaTeX compilation error: LaTeX Error: File `standalone.cls' not found.                  tex_file_writing.py:312
ERROR    Context of error:                                                                       tex_file_writing.py:346                             -> \documentclass[preview]{standalone}
                         \usepackage[english]{babel}
                         \usepackage{amsmath}

                INFO     You do not have package standalone.cls installed.                                       tex_file_writing.py:356                    INFO     Install standalone.cls it using your LaTeX package manager, or check for typos.         tex_file_writing.py:356                    ERROR    LaTeX compilation error: Emergency stop.                                                tex_file_writing.py:312
                ERROR    Context of error:                                                                       tex_file_writing.py:346                             -> \documentclass[preview]{standalone}

                         \usepackage[english]{babel}
                         \usepackage{amsmath}

[...]
ValueError: latex error converting to dvi. See log output above or the log file: media\Tex\88663fadf5843031.log
I have successfully installed LaTeX (it gives me the version in the command prompt and works without text containing math elements). I've also tried replacing MathTex with Tex or using two dollar signs instead of one, but nothing works. What should I do?

you need to install standalone, you have given no information about which tex system you are using, with texlive from tug that would be tlmgr install standalone if you have a linux system texlive install via apt or whichever package manager you use, although you seem to be using \  so are you using windows, miktex will have an install option in its console

I'm sorry i'm complete beginner in Latex (and in programming in general) I've installed Texlive on Winwdows. Could you please detail your answer?

oh in that case at the windows commandline it should be enough to type tlmgr install standalone you must have opted to install a subset of the full texlive originally.

I got this message : Cross release updates are only supported with
update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.    Should I install Latex again or is there anything else that I could do? (I'm sorry to take a part of your time I feel like an old grandma struggling to connect to her wifi)

so that probably means that you installed texlive 2023 and things have moved on and it's now texlive 2024, the simplest thing to do is probably install texlive 2024

ok thank you so much
